# Add USB 3.0 port

Tags: usb, motherboard

I have a pretty old samsung NP300e5x laptop which does not have a USB 3.0 slot, but I would like to have one at handy for obvious transfer speed reasons. 
The available ports on my laptop are 3XUSB 2.0, ethernet, VGA, HDMI,SD card slot, AUX, and an optical Drive but do not have an PCI Express card slot.

So, is there any way USB 3.0 can be installed on this laptop, I am willing to tinker on the board and ditch any existing slot too.

Thanks.

Comment: No, you cannot add USB3 to a laptop that does not support it.

Comment: There are, in fact, [USB 3.0 controllers in the Mini PCIe format](https://geizhals.de/?cat=ioexpcard&xf=4292_2~621_PCIe+Mini+Card). *However*, they cannot fit into a notebook’s constrained space. You would also have to sacrifice the WiFi card to install it, probably.

Comment: Can I replace the ODD with something that can support the USB 3.0 via the SATA connector that connects the ODD, something like a secondary hdd connection?

Comment: @MayankChoudhury No, that’s unfortunately impossible. SATA and USB 3.0 are completely different.

Answer (score 1):

There is no economically feasible way to add USB 3.0 support to a laptop that lacks a PCIe slot.